# How to inject fragment with a view model factory for instrumentation testing in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, dagger-2, android-testing

I have the following Dagger component setup which works well for my app.

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        ApiModule::class,
        DatabaseModule::class,
        ViewModelModule::class,
        ActivityModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

I wish to provide a custom implementation for the ApiModule (Retrofit mock) and DatabaseModule (InMemory Room DB) for instrumentation testing. So I created a test component as below:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        MockApiModule::class,
        TestDatabaseModule::class,
        ViewModelModule::class,
        ActivityModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class
    ]
)
interface TestComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): TestComponent
    }
}
```

My fragment requires an injection of ViewModelProvider.Factory

```
class MovieListingFragment : BaseFragment() {
    @Inject lateinit var factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val vm: MovieViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.mobile_navigation) { factory }
```

which I'm generating using the ViewModelModule as below:

```
@Module
interface ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MovieViewModel::class)
    fun bindMovieViewModel(vm: MovieViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

***How do I inject this in the fragment under test?***

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MovieListFragmentTest {
    @Test
    fun testMovieListFragment() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<MovieListingFragment>()
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of ways to approach this but the approach that worked best for me was to create a special `mock` buildType with a different dependency injection setup for the APIs where I didn't want to use the "real thing". My UI tests would then be under `src/androidTestMock` so that it runs the `mock` buildType.

You'll also have to:

1. Interface your APIs so you can provide mocks or real implementations for your build types
2. Implement your non-mocked DI setup not in your main sources but in each of your build types (e.g. debug, release). This only applies for the APIs that need special versions in your `mock` build type. Modules that are the "real thing" across all build types go into your main sources. This will lead to some code duplication that, if you really want to, you can avoid by having a non-mock source set.
3. Make sure your mocked classes are provided as singletons or your test (which will be doing the mocking or the different test setup) will receive a different instance than your app.
4. Make sure to CI/CD your mock built type too since you will mostly be working with other build types and you'll want catch a broken compile early.

In your case you'd have the `TestComponent` in src/mock, and `AppComponent` in src/debug and src/release.